Ubuntu 20.04 Can't set system variables using mysqld with OS errno: 13 - Permission denied
I need to change innodb_buffer_pool_size in a MySQL server running on Ubuntu 20.04. I'm getting Permission denied error on the default data directory /var/lib/mysql/ although mysql is the owner of that dir, as it seems it should be. The MySQL database has no problems starting or running queries from Workbench or mysql> from the command line.
$ mysqld --innodb-buffer-pool-size=16G --innodb-buffer-pool-instances=32;
2024-07-09T18:27:23.345077Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2024-07-09T18:27:23.345117Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) starting as process 7624
2024-07-09T18:27:23.346832Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2024-07-09T18:27:23.346836Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2024-07-09T18:27:23.346921Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010122] [Server] One can only use the --user switch if running as root
2024-07-09T18:27:23.346927Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (OS errno: 13 - Permission denied)
2024-07-09T18:27:23.346959Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-07-09T18:27:23.347042Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3)  (Ubuntu).

$ sudo ls -l  /var/lib/
drwx------  8 mysql         mysql         36864 Jul  9 14:30 mysql

Does anyone know what this error is about and how to fix it?

I got around the issue by setting the variable in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
Added two lines to the end of mysqld.cnf:
innodb-buffer-pool-size = 16G
innodb-buffer-pool-instances = 32
Then after restarting the server, the buffer pool size had been set:
mysql> SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024;
+------------------------------------------+
| @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024 |
+------------------------------------------+
|                          16.000000000000 |
+------------------------------------------+

